# php: what is the difference between functions getting their variables between brachets and using a $_session[variable] in a function?

Tags: php, variables

I wondered what is the difference between
$x, $y, $z being variables declared and the function($x,$y,$z)

and

$_SESSION['x'], $_SESSION['y'],$_SESSION['z'] declared
and 
function() using $_SESSION['x'], $_SESSION['y'], $_SESSION['z'];

Best regards, thanks.

Comment: You wrote that you wonder what is the difference.  Why do you think they're the same?

Comment: because both functions work with the same variables but in the second I don't have to worry about the order of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the first scenario, the values are provided to the function by whatever invokes that function.  In the second, the function actively seeks out the variables from the session.  The distinction between the two comes down to where the responsibility for finding the values should happen.

The session is a *dependency*.  So if the function relies on the session, then the function has an internal dependency.  This limits the versatility of the function.

If the function accepts the values as arguments, any PHP code anywhere can use the code in that function.  If the function pulls the values from session state, then only an active web application can use that function.  *Plus* that web application has to remember to put the values where the function can find them (since it doesn't *advertise* that it needs those values, as function arguments do).

In the majority of cases, the first approach is preferred.  If the function performs an operation (and optionally returns a result), then have the function *just do that*.  Have it "do one thing".  The responsibility of providing the function with what it needs belongs to the code which calls the function.  The function itself, as a fully-encapsulated entity, should simply advertise what it needs and what it is expected to return.